# Whenever I update state of element it change the state all my elements but I don't want that

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the state of only one element at a time whenever I use setState()  like current, dur, bar variables in the code.

**The array created by map function I want when I setState of element it will make change in only one element.**

```
const Audio = () => {
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState("00:00");
    const [dur, setDur] = useState("00:00");
    const [bar, setBar] = useState("0%");

    const playPause = (event,id, index) => {
        let audio = document.getElementById(id);
            audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause()
    }
    const timeUpdate = (id) => {
        let audio = document.getElementById(id);
        let rawtimedur = parseInt(audio.duration);
        let curTime = audio.currentTime;
        setCurrent(curTime);
        setDur(rawtimedur);
    };
    var songs = {
        "song": [{
            "id": 1,
            "src": "http://192.168.1.15:4000/video/audio.mp3",
            "title": "La calin",
            "artist": "Sernath Drums"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "src": "http://192.168.1.15:4000/video/audio2.mp3",
            "title": "Ek Raat",
            "artist": "Dark Music Production"
        }
        ]
    }
   
    return (
        <div className='body'>
            {songs.song.map((data, index)=>{
                return <div className="audio-container" key={data.id.toString()}>
                    <h3>{data.title}</h3>
                    <h5>{data.artist}</h5>
                <div className="audio-progress">
                        <div className="current">{current}</div>
                        <div className="length">{dur}</div>
                    <div className="bar-postion" onClick={(event)=>skip(event, data.id)}>
                        <div className="audio-bar" style={{ width: `${bar}%` }}>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <audio id={data.id} src={data.src}></audio>
                </div>
            </div>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Audio
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific of what you want? Explain it, give us a code you tried to use that did not work for you? With this little information + the bad grammar, It's hard to understand what you mean. If you want to edit only 1 element of `songs` then do so? But save it as a state and modify that element of what u need. + don't use `var` always use `let` or `const`

Comment: Currently your code seems to be sharing only one state with all the mapped components. You need to encapsulate the state logic at the single component level to make them independent of each other

Comment: I want to setSate of only one element whenever I update the state of current variable.

Comment: current is variable in the code.